# Change shape of bootstrap modal view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is there a way to change the background shape of a Twitter Bootstrap modal view (to a diamond or a circle, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try edit the following code in bootstrap.css

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 560px;
  margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

also the other modal related css